# How to concatenate if statement into a string?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, concatenation

Here is my code on one of my templates...

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) :
the_post();             
the_content();  
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=5' );      
endwhile; ?>
    <ul id="on-going">
<?php       $terms = get_terms( 
    'series', array( 
        'orderby' =>'name'));
         foreach( $terms as $t ){ 
            $t_id = $t->term_id; $series = get_option("taxonomy_$t_id");
         if( $series['status_term_meta'] != 1 ) continue; ?>
        <li>
        <a title="See all <?php echo $t->name; ?> Episodes" href="<?php       echo                 home_url(); ?>
        /series/<?php echo $t->
        slug; ?>"> 
        <?php echo( strlen($t->
        name) > 25)?substr( $t->name, 0, 25 ) . '...':$t->name; ?> </a>
        <?php if(is_subbed($t->slug)) {
        echo'<span class="subbedcolor small rightside"> SUBBED </span> '; 
    }
        if(is_dubbed($t->slug)){
        echo'<span class="dubbedcolor small rightside"> DUBBED </span> ';
        }
         ?>
```

I want to take the part

```
  <?php if(is_subbed($t->slug)) {
        echo'<span class="subbedcolor small rightside"> SUBBED </span> '; 
    }
        if(is_dubbed($t->slug)){
        echo'<span class="dubbedcolor small rightside"> DUBBED </span> ';
        }
```

and include it into my other template so it will show if an episode is subbed, or dubbed:

Here is the string for the other code:

```
    $page = $page . "<li><a style='display:block;' title='" . $name . "' href='" . home_url(). "/series/" .$term->slug . "'>" . $name ."</a></li>";
```

How would I include the subbed or dubbed part after the closing li tag? I tried to concatenate the if statement, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks so much if anyone can figure it out :D

Answer (score 0):

You said that concatenation didn't work. What did you try and what didn't work?

Try this:

```
if(is_subbed($t->slug)) {
    $page = $page.'<span class="subbedcolor small rightside"> SUBBED </span> '; 
}
    if(is_dubbed($t->slug)){
    $page = $page.'<span class="dubbedcolor small rightside"> DUBBED </span> ';
    }
```